# Owncloud seems to ignore dbtype in config.php (using docker)

Tags: mysql, sqlite, owncloud, qnap

I’m an Owncloud newbie and would like to deploy a containerized version of `Owncloud` on my `NAS (QNAP)` as a private alternative to Dropbox.
I can run a docker container of `Owncloud` without any problem using the default `sqlite` database: I access the GUI, create the admin user, browse the file structure, etc.
But I’d like to switch to `Mysql` and I was so far unable to do as `Owncloud` “seems” to ignore the settings in `config.php`.

I created a MySQL instance (MariaDB) in a separate container and added an empty `owncloud-reserved database` to it: I verified that from the `Owncloud` container I can successfully login into the MySQL’s via the command line using the appropriate credentials, so the database is reachable.

Following some instructions I found online I edited file `config.php` and changed field “installed” in variable $CONFIG from “true” to “false”: this triggers the db configuration wizard upon login.
In the wizard I select “MySQL” and await the completion of the setup procedure.
When it’s done I checked that:

1. `Owncloud` tables have been created in the MariaDB database (the db was empty before running the wizard)
2. The `config.php` file has been modified and now I see all `mysql db` settings, particulary:
   `'dbtype' => 'mysql'`,
   (the file showed before the sqlite settings)

So apparently the wizard did his stuff.

Despite the above, if I go to the Settings page of my admin user, under General I still see the red warning: “`SQLite` is used as database…etc”.
For testing, I added a new user and indeed the data are still stored in the `sqlite` file rather than MySQL

So my conclusion is that `Owncloud` is ignoring `config.php` in my setup.

Things I tried to no avail:

Recreating the `Owncloud` container multiple times
Restart the container after the database change
Running the suggested `sqlite` to `mysql` migration script as per the `owncloud` official documentation

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance
Regards
Sergio

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Adding the following variables with appropriate values to the container's environment did the trick:

```
OWNCLOUD_DB_TYPE=mysql
OWNCLOUD_DB_HOST=name or ip of the host (container) where the db is running
OWNCLOUD_DB_NAME=name of the database
OWNCLOUD_DB_USERNAME=name of the user to authenticate with (must have full privs on the db)
OWNCLOUD_DB_PASSWORD=its password
```

Thanks
S.

Comment: This was the answer I've been looking for after wasting 3 hours chasing misleading logs. This is not well documented. Thanks.